# Is preloading data into session variables with AJAX upon login a good idea?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, database-performance

I've created a subscription-based system that deals with a large data-set.  In its first iteration, it had semi-complicated joins that would execute, based on user-set filters, on every 'data view' page.  Each query would fetch anywhere from a few kilobytes to several megabytes depending on the filter range.  I decided this was unacceptable and so learned about APC (I had heard about its data-store features).

I  moved all of the strings out of the queries into an APC preload routine that fires upon first login.  In the same routine, I am running the "full set" join query to get all of the possible IDs for the data set into a $_SESSION variable.  The entire set is anywhere from 100-800Kb, depending on what data the customer is subscribed to.

I convert this set into a JSON array and shuffle the data around dynamically when the user changes the filters.  In creating the system I wanted it to seem as if the user was moving around lots of data very quickly, with minimal page loading (AJAX + APC when string representations are needed), as they played with the filters.

My multipart question is, is it possible for the user to effectively "cancel" the initial cache/query routine by surfing to another page after the first login?  If so, can I move this process to an AJAX page for preloading, or does this carry the same problem?  Or, am I just going about all of this in the wrong way?  I came up with the idea on my own and I'm worried that I've created an unusable monster.

Also, I've been warned that my questions suck and I'm in danger of being banned.  Every question I've asked has come from a position of intelligent wonder, written as well as I knew how at the time, and so it's really aggravating when an outsider votes me down without intelligent criticism.  Just tell me what I did wrong and I will quickly fix the problem. Bichis.

Comment: Preparing a subset of the data that the current user will work on with is not a monster or a stupid idea - just the opposite this is the best practice actually. The alternative is to hit the DB regularly with queries that produce huge similar results and this is not helping for the performance of the system. Personally I will make all this preparation to be asynchronous. Initially the client see some Welcome page while the data set is prepared for the session.

Comment: Ah, yes, thank you.  I know what you mean by asynchronous, which is what I was saying about loading it in AJAX.  But my question was will that preload cancel if the user surfs away from the "welcome" page too quickly?

Comment: That depend on the realization that you implement. What I will do is avoid using AJAX initially , so it dosent metter if the user surfs away or not. Instead just send some static page to the browser (do not forget to flush() the buffers) after that prepare the huge data that is unique for the session.